# Vimeo player not getting thumbnails due to erroneous requests to CDN

Tags: thumbnails, nan, cdn, vimeo

Yesterday, we had major problems with one of our websites due to erroneous requests being sent to the Vimeo CDN. The requests looked like this:

https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/[videoId].webp?mw=NaN&mh=NaN&q=70

(The erroneous part is the value "NaN" for the parameters *mw* and *mh*)

The videos are embedded like this on our website:

```
<iframe id="part-1" width="100%" height="450" 
src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/[videoId]?api=1&player_id=part-1" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When using this method, it seems like it's actually **Vimeo** who is making the requests to the CDN in order to get the thumbnail for the video. Increase the size of the result window in this fiddle and see how requests to the Vimeo CDN gets sent: https://jsfiddle.net/azbsxLej/2/.

My questions:

1. Was it our website or Vimeo making those erroneous requests?
2. Any ideas to why the parameters *mw* and *mh* were set to NaN, which caused our problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Part of reply from Vimeo, who by the way, replied very fast and was very helpful:

> The errors you encountered were related to a bug in our player, which
>   should now be resolved. We sincerely apologize for any inconvenience.